# View log files from EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ec2

I am deploying a python application using nginx/uwsgi on aws.

What is the best/recommended way to view the log files produced from those two modules (in `/var/log/uwsgi` and `/var/log/nginx`) as also some custom application log files e.g. in `/my/app/logfiles/error.log` etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best and easiest way to keep track of your logs is using [Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/details/).

For an overview, read the [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/view-aws-codedeploy-logs-in-amazon-cloudwatch-console/). To setup/install the CloudWatch Logs agent, read [Getting Started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_GettingStarted.html).

Your EC2 instance will also need an IAM role allowing it to write logs.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute easiest way to view your EC2 logs without configuring additional utilities or permissions is to use native linux commands.

After you SSH onto your machine, you can use `tail -n 50 -f /path/to/logfile.log` to view the last 50 lines of your log file. The `-f` argument tells `tail` to keep watching the log file and print out any new entries that are made.

You can also use `grep` to search long or frequently changing log files for terms. Use `grep '<your search string>' /path/to/logfile.log | less` to find lines matching a query and page through them